# can you have two brushes in dynamic painting?

Tags: dynamic-paint

Not getting the other brush to function , my question is that can you have two brushes in dynamicpainting painting the same canvas. ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.
... "any" number of mesh objects (set as Brush) should work for the same Canvas object.

[image]

[image]

Blender Manual for more info check **[Dynamic Paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/dynamic_paint/index.html)**

When you have any issue, it is always good way to open a new file and test it with maximum of default setups, if still issue "Load factory settings" and test again.

BTW answering given Q didn't move you forward and didn't solve your issue ... try to edit your Q with something more specific that we can solve for you :)